# django select app(s) for syncdb

Tags: python, django, django-syncdb, syncdb, django-manage.py

First of all: please don't ask me: "Why would you need this?".

Now the question itself: I have several applications installed in INSTALLED_APPS. Database is now empty and I want to synchronise only some of apps. What's the simplest way to do this?

I know I can write my custom management command based on syncdb. But it's a shame syncdb is designed in such a way that I would have to copy/paste a large chunk of code, changing only one line. This is a reason I want to explore other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `managed = False` in the `Meta` class of a model. When this attribute is set, `syncdb` won't manage the app's tables for you. You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed).

Another way would be to write a custom router

```
class MyAppRouter(object):
    """A router to control all database operations on models in
    the myapp application"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        pass

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        pass

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        pass

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if model._meta.app_label in ['myapp1', 'myapp2']
            return False
```

Comment: Too much hassle - I would have to loop through all models in all apps, remember previous state of the flag, then restore it afterwards. Is's easier to write a custom command...

Comment: No, I'm calling syncdb in my custom command, which exports model data from one database to another. If in target DB there is no tables I want to create them by syncdb but I need to create tables only for the application I'm exporting.

Comment: Not quite. I wan't to create reusable application for migrations. You can specify source and target DBs as a parameter of new management command as well as application, which data should be migrated. You can't achieve it using routers.

Comment: @mnowotka: I have used [this](http://diegobz.net/2011/02/10/django-database-router-using-settings/) generic router with great success

Answer (score 0):

You can install `django-extensions`, enable it and use it's useful commands like:

```
./manage.py sqldiff APP_NAME
```

It will print out a list of SQL commands that you can run to syncdb your apps by name.

Django-extensions docs here: https://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

For launch migration by app there is `app_label` argument:

> `<app_label>`: The specified app has its migrations run, up to the most
>   recent migration. This may involve running other apps’ migrations too,
>   due to dependencies.

Example

```
./manage.py migrate myapp
```

See [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate).

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work - `python manage.py syncdb  --database=NEW_APP_DB`